# How can I replace a hard-coded value with a display map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to replace the Hard coded display with Array Map(or similar functions) ,

```
const arr = [
  { description: 'A', value: 10 },
  { description: 'B', value: 5 },
  { description: 'C', value: 10 },
  { description: 'D', value: 10 },
];
```

```
return (
<Parent>
  <Row>
    <Content> arr[0].description+": "+arr[0].value</Content>
    <Content> arr[1].description+": "+arr[1].value</Content>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Content> arr[2].description+": "+arr[2].value</Content>
    <Content> arr[3].description+": "+arr[3].value</Content>
  </Row>
</Parent>
);
```

I am not sure why I can't use Array map and have a tag without its closing tag like below

```
arr.map((item, index) => {
  const ContentJSX = <Content>item.description + ": "+ item.value</Content>;
  if (index % 2 === 0) return '<Row>' + ContentJSX;
  else return ContentJSX + '</Row>';
});
```

Any leads or alternative approach is appreciated.

Comment: Restructure the array so it's an array of row arrays. Then use two nested `.map()`s.

Comment: Because each returned element from `array.prototype.map` needs to be a valid JSX node, in other words it needs to be a valid and complete node, opening and closing tag. Just group the array elements into nested arrays that represent each "row" you want to map, and then also map the nested "content".